# Labyrinth: old freeware to organise characters and plot

Tags: software, tools, planning

I found this freeware app, labytrinth, years ago. It allowed to create elements (characters, places, objects, etc) and detail information about them. Then you could drag these elements into a wide area where you could set relationships in between them (arrows with little text tags). It also had a function where you could create a table with place / chapters / characters / etc in order to organise your plot and determine who was doing what and where. It was very basic: no colours, no great variety of arrows, but it worked perfectly.

Last year I discovered YEd, an app that allows you to create extremely intricate diagrams, with variety of colours, shapes, arrows, etc, and it can also automaticaly rearrange all the elements. I've started using it because the diagram part is very useful, but, unlike Labyrinth, each element is created from scratch. So, if you decide to change the name of a character, labyrinth would automatically update the name in every diagram which included that element, whereas I have to change each diagram manually in YEd. For this reason, I never got around to transport all the information I had inserted into Labyrinth concerning a Fantasy series I'm planning.

This series comprises of 5 books, with the first four being completely planned by now. I have over one hundred characters with their relationships carefully anotated.

And my computer crashed.

I lost no files because I make regular backups but... I never did make a backup of the app. And now I can't find it online.

So, please, has anyone heard of this app (or freeware programme) and can direct me to a site where I can download it so that I can recover the information I've got locked in the files?

The name of the app is Labyrinth and it creates files with the PLT extension. I have tried PLT viewers with no success at all. Here is an image of a diagram made with the app:

[image]

EDIT:
I started using it 3 or 4 years ago and both the site and the look of the app gave me the feel that it was something that had been created at least 5 to 10 years before. It runs on Windows.

---

**Conclusion**

A helpful user at stack overflow has directed me towards Python and graphviz as a way to read the diagrams. Another way is to manually associate ID numbers to names, events, relationships and slowly (manually) recover the connections. Either way, It'll take time, but I can recover everything.

I'll tell you all one thing: when people say not to bother with backing up software because it's all online and you'll have to go online to get the most up to date version anyway... Only photos you'd rather be forgotten stay online forever, so back everything else up. Better safe than sorry.

Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: How exactly old is that application and what platform were you running it on? The screenshot looks like it was made on a Mac from the early 90s?

Comment: @Lew: I'll add that info to the question.

Comment: Is this it? https://people.gnome.org/~dscorgie/labyrinth.html

Comment: @mbakeranalecta No, I'm afraid not. I tried to instal the Windows Installer, just in case it was a different version of 'my' Labyrinth, and it's not even an experimental app, just a text to see how the app runs on Windows, so... no, it's not it.

Comment: I tried the Internet Wayback Machine. The website was Habitual Indolence. Here's the page; not sure if the links work: https://web.archive.org/web/20160211174035/http://www.habitualindolence.net/labyrinth/ I was able to get the zip to DL, but I'm on a Mac so I don't know if it will work for you.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum YES! This is exactly it! But Wayback Machine tells me it "doesn't have that page archived."

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Could you run me through your steps? Did you just download the installer from the page? Were you logged in on Wayback Machine?

Comment: I tried both the installer and the binaries for the latest version and it said it didn't have those pages archived. There was no option of logging in.

Comment: Try writing to the email address given on the tech support page: labyrinth@habitualindolence.net

Comment: @mbakeranalecta: I have followed your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: If you search for "habitualindolence labyrinth" on Google, you can find a number of forum and Google Group discussions. Try to contact the members there and see if someone still has the app and will mail it to you.

Comment: Do the files have more than one file ending, e.g. "file.jpg.ptl" or something like that? Then try to remove the ".ptl" and open the file without that ending. Also, try opening a **copy** of one of the files in a text editor such as Notepad++. What do you see? Just special character soup, or something that looks like meaningful code? PTL could be something Python and might be interpreted with another software. Also, for the future, always backup your whole harddisk.

Comment: I wasn't logged in to anything. The link which I pasted came up. I went to Downloads on the left. I right-clicked on the installer link and chose Save Link As, and that gave me the zip file. If all else fails, send me an email at the address in my profile and I'll send you the zip which I downloaded. I can't make any promises because I can't use the file, but you're welcome to whatever I was able to get.

Comment: I tried opening the zip you get from Save Link As and you get a corrupt file that won't open.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Despit S. Mitchell's bad experience with the file, I think I'll give it a try.

Comment: @what .ptl is the sole extension. It does open with notepad: it gives the information I had written for the characters as well as the positions and the coordinates for the arrows connecting the diagram elements. I don't know how code works, but it reminds me of how I used to write webpages with html, back in 2005. Could a web browser be able to read it? If not, and if it is Python, as you say, what keywords should I use to look for a programme that could read this code?

Comment: @what I've found a python visualiser online and tried part of the code but it gave me an invalid syntax error. The first two lines are: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">. Does that give a hint about what could visualise the code?

Comment: @SaraCosta So apparently what you have is an XML file with items and coordinates. This would allow you to plot the items on a coordinate system. Maybe you should go to Stack Overflow, post the contents of a sample file and ask for help in visualizing this code. What I'm saying is that the information is not lost, and is accessible in the file, but it might take some knowledge to turn it into something readable for you.

Comment: @what ok, I'll head over there ASAP. I have been sending emails in the meantime, as mbakeranalecta and you yourself suggested. Thanks to all of your interest and help I'm confident I'll manage to recover the information.

Comment: @SaraCosta While this entire exchange is atypical for this board, please come back and let us know how it worked out! :)

Comment: This question is a good example of why I prefer to use a pencil and paper – or a data format that a wide range of software can interpret.

Comment: @SaraCosta: Since you have a valid answer, you may put it up as an answer, and mark as accepted :)

Answer (score 7):

I used the link posted by Ryann Foxx earlier, decompiled the code, and ported it to modern Windows and Linux. Basically everything is the same except it used a collections library that can't work in the modern version of the language, plus a widgetry library from 2003 that's hackily supported at best today. I also checked it for malware. There was none but if you don't believe me you can compile it from scratch using the source code I posted.

My code is [here](https://github.com/Zekka/labyrinth3). If you think I seem trustworthy, you can download `Release.public.zip` from the Releases section [here](https://github.com/Zekka/labyrinth3/releases/) and all you'll need to do is unzip the ZIP file. Otherwise you can download it and compile it yourself. I included some hotfixes that mostly affect Linux which you can disable in Program.cs.

The documentation strongly implies that this was distributed with partial source code originally under a "do what you want but don't sell it" basis so I don't feel too bad about redistributing it in source format.

Note that Ryann's version mostly worked fine for me on modern W10 -- it was really only Linux that I ran into problems on. But I did feel a little skeeved out running random EXE files from the internet, so I'm hoping this helps any nervous people. If nothing else, my Github repo is likely to last longer than Ryann's Dropbox.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit wary about posting this as an answer, but I just pulled [a copy of Labyrinth](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ykwsal2ci9rjmzg/Labyrinth.zip?dl=0) from my computer. It should still work.

One warning is that it may only work if placed in Program Files (or Program Files (x86)). If so, it should be put under `Karetao\Labyrinth`.

I'm unable to provide a version for Mac, if one existed, but this is the only working copy I have been able to find.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an app that tries to make plotting out your story very easy: [Plottr](http://www.plotmynovel.com)

It's got a timeline that is a very graphical way to show each story line (main plot and subplots) and each scene. Across the top are the scenes and along the side are the story lines.

The nice thing is that you can flip it so the scenes are down the side and the story lines are across the top. It's better for some people to see it like that.

Where the scene and story line intersect you can add a card which is just a place you can write a description about what happens at the intersection of those two.

You can even drag and drop cards easily anywhere around the timeline.

It also has a place for general notes, a place for characters, and a place for settings. For characters and settings you can add custom attributes which is really handy.

And the notes you can tag with your characters or places.

I use it for my stories and it's been invaluable